# Make firefox window transparent on Gnome-Shell

Tags: linux, firefox, gnome, gnome-shell

How can I make the top part of Firefox (AKA the tabs/settings bar/bookmarks/url bar) transparent on Gnome-Shell? I've searched, but didn't find any answer. I mainly want to make it semi-transparent so that my desktop can be seen behind.

Comment: Can't say for sure bu I really doubt this is possible. You could _maybe_ do it for all programs but not for a specific part of the GUI of a particular program, at least not without editing its source.

Answer (score 0):

this [Gnome Shell Extension](https://github.com/saysilence/transparentwindows) maybe helpfull for you. With this you may enable transparency globally for all windows, or for specific window.